# Prove (or disprove) the equivalence of AP, LUB, NIT and MCT

Tags: real-analysis

Recently I have been given a very interesting problem. The problem is to check whether the following holds,

$\color{red}{\text{Archimedean Property}}\\\iff \color{blue}{\text{Least Upper Bound Axiom}}\\\iff \color{Green}{\text{Monotone Convergence Theorem}}\\\iff \color{deeppink}{\text{Nested Interval Theorem}}$

Where in brief the results are,

> **Archimedean Property (AP)**
>
> $$\forall \varepsilon :\varepsilon\in \mathbb{R}^+,\exists n_0\in \mathbb{N}\mid n_0\varepsilon>1$$
>
> **Least Upper Bound Axiom (LUB)**
>
> $$A\subset \mathbb{R}: \left(\exists m\in \mathbb{R}\mid m\ge a,\forall a\in A\right) \implies \left(\exists m_0\in \mathbb{R}: (m_0\ge a, \forall a\in A)\land(\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists a_0\in A\mid m_0-\varepsilon<a_0\le m_0\right))$$
>
> **Nested Interval Theorem (NIT)**
>
> $$\left(I_n=[a_n,b_n]:a_n,b_n\in \mathbb{R}\ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}\right)\land\left(\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n-a_n)=0\right)\implies\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n\ne \emptyset$$
>
> **Monotone Convergence Theorem (MCT)**
>
> $$\{a_n\}_{n\ge 1}:(a_{i+1}\ge a_i)\land (\exists m\mid m\ge a_n,\forall n)\implies \exists l\in \mathbb{R}\mid\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=l$$

The proof of the equivalence, $$\color{blue}{\text{LUB}}\implies \color{red}{\text{AP}}\implies \color{Green}{\text{MCT}}\implies \color{deeppink}{\text{NIT}}$$ is trivial and has been completed. I am currently considering the following four problems,

- When I have tried to prove the following, $$\color{deeppink}{\text{NIT}}\implies\color{blue}{\text{LUB}}\implies \color{red}{\text{AP}}\implies \color{Green}{\text{MCT}}$$ I couldn't do that because I could prove LUB using AP and NIT both but not using NIT only. I thought that if I assume that there doesn't exist the LUB then NIT would be contradicted and so I tried to prove LUB assuming that there doesn't exist any LUB but couldn't obtain any contradiction. Any ideas how to do it?
- When I tried to prove $$\color{Green}{\text{MCT}}\implies\color{deeppink}{\text{NIT}}\implies\color{blue}{\text{LUB}}\implies \color{red}{\text{AP}}$$ then only thing that I couldn't show is that $l$ should be *an* upper bound of the sequence $\{a_n\}$. Any ideas how to do it?
- Lastly when I tried to prove $$\color{red}{\text{AP}}\implies\color{Green}{\text{MCT}}\implies\color{deeppink}{\text{NIT}}\implies\color{blue}{\text{LUB}}$$ I found myself totally lost. Any ideas as to where to begin?

It will also be very helpful if someone would give remarks for the general problem, i.e.

$$\boxed{\color{red}{\text{AP}}\iff \color{blue}{\text{LUB}}\iff \color{Green}{\text{MCT}}\iff \color{deeppink}{\text{NIT}}}$$

Comment: For a very detailed (perhaps too detailed for your purposes)  discussion of this category of problems, please see Propp's  [Real Analysis in Reverse.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4483.pdf)

Comment: @AndréNicolas: This is simply wonderful.

Comment: Propp's paper is very useful, I jumped at the opportunity to recommend it.  You might want to answer your own question, not in detail, there are too many parts, but giving an instance or two from the paper.